# Error after converting to Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, prefix

After I converted my project to Swift 3.0, I find error in log from variable:

```
var arrayOfHours = stringArray.map {String(describing: $0!.characters.prefix(2))}
```

Error is:

```
code of error:  "Optional(Swift.String.CharacterView(_core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: Optional(0x000060800024ee70), _countAndFlags: 2, _owner: Optional(Swift._HeapBufferStorage<Swift._StringBufferIVars,
 Swift.UInt16>))))"
```

where is my error occuring?

**Update:**

```
var stringArray in console: [Optional("1226"), Optional("1249"), Optional("1312"), Optional("1336"), Optional("1359"), Optional("1422"), Optional("1446"), Optional("1509"), Optional("1532"), Optional("1549"), Optional("1607"), Optional("1624"), Optional("1642"), Optional("1659"), Optional("1717"), Optional("1734"), Optional("1752"), Optional("1809"), Optional("1827"), Optional("1844"), Optional("1902"), Optional("1919"), Optional("1954"), Optional("2032"), Optional("2107"), Optional("2142"), Optional("2217"), Optional("2252"), Optional("2327"), Optional("2402"), Optional("2437"), Optional("2512")]
```

Comment: How is `stringArray` defined and what does it contain? Why forced unwrapping in `$0!`? What would the expected output be? – As always, a small *self-contained* example would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Using `String(describing:)` means that you "force" something to be a string which isn't a string, instead of properly converting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var stringArray: [String?] = ["1226", "1249"]
print(stringArray) // [Optional("1226"), Optional("1249")]

var arrayOfHours = stringArray.map { String($0!.characters.prefix(2)) }
print(arrayOfHours) // ["12", "12"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You decided my problem and app is working! Great!

Comment: Ohh did the conversion mess up your stringArray form optional string??

Answer (score 0):

Well its giving you an `Optional` of the String casting because `String()` will return nil if it found something else rather than a `String`, So what you'll have to do is unwrap that as in :

```
stringArray.map {String(describing: $0!.characters.prefix(2))!}
```

Just added an force unwrap `!` to the `String()` result

Comment: ok, i did it and see error: Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String'